# GeForce 210 and its outputs

Tags: displayport

I have [GeForce 210](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2939) graphic card. could I plug in my extension cables in all of its 3 outputs and get output at the same time or I have to plug into one output at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to its user manual.

Comment: It would be helpful if someone would do so and also post that information here, so it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

All outputs should be supported simultaneously.